# What constitutes "interaction" in the text of this error? play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

I'm building an extension that is randomly (5% chance or so) going to play a jingle.

I've this code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const myAudio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL("not_work_safe_jingle.mp3"));
            myAudio.play();
        }, 3000);
    }

}, false);
```

I have to set click to avoid this error:

> play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Buuut... I'm curious if there's something more generic that *counts* as an interaction. Scrolling would be ideal but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else other than keystrokes and clicks?

Comment: Erm... apart from keystrokes and mouse actions, how can you interact with a webpage?

Comment: @JackBashford You can hover over stuff. Hover can trigger JS to do anything to the page. I'd argue that's interacting - same as scrolling.

Comment: why don't you just set an interval instead of a timeout for however often you want it to maybe play a jingle, and do the random number logic inside the setInterval

Comment: User gesture flag expires after 1 second so you need to reduce the timer. Scrolling and hovering isn't interacting as it's similar to looking at a person or walking around vs talking/touching. The actual details are in the specification for User Activation.

Comment: More info: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5722065667620864